# Arm goes numb during chair dips?

Tags: biceps

I have an issue where my arms go sorta tingly and numb after about 25 chair dips. I can still do reps afterward (have gone up to 42) however my arms feel really weird doing it. Nothing like they normally do after I am getting tired from push ups.

It is worth noting that that point of 25 has been slowly going higher, but at a much slower rate than my maximum reps is going up.

What could be going on here? How can I make it better?

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your arms are in such an angle that bloodflow is slightly cut off, which would cause this feeling of going numb.

Are you doing the dips behind your body (assuming you are since the title says chair dips)? In that case you could try doing dips on parallel bars. This way your arms aren't as far back (basically next to your body) which could solve the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is right, chair dips are unnecessarily stressful on the shoulder joint.

Comment: @JJosaur - Do chair dips place more stress on the shoulder than regular dips?

Comment: [This has a strong baseball slant but for the majority of the population, bench dips really can be unnecessary](http://ericcressey.com/baseball-strength-training-programs-dips). I understand that a lot of shoulder movements can be damaging if done wrong (snatch grip behind the neck press, looking at you) but are very useful for developing strength. With all of them athletes should be mindful of the forces involved and take risks knowing all the facts.

Comment: I don't really have the gear to do regular dips as I am purposely trying to avoid the gym or buying any fitness equipment. Is there a better bodyweight type exercises that work on the chest, back, and forearm muscled? I am already doing pushups.

Comment: You can place to chairs so that you can have your body in between and still do this type of dip without parallel bars. Dips mainly work your shoulders, chest and triceps. If you want to strengthen your back you could do pull-ups or inverted rows at home. Place a broom stick on two chairs and you got yourself a bar to do inverted rows on :)